# Put a part of a text in bold in \sexp with Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I used a condition to display 2 differents text with Sweave.
After that, I display this text.

But I would like to bold a part of my first text.

```
<<condition, echo=FALSE>>=
if (x > 0) {
  text <- paste("text 1 start :",paste(variables, collapse = ","), ". text 1 end.")
  } else {
    text <- paste("text 2")
  }
@

\Sexpr{text}
```

Here, the actual output in my report.pdf is:

text 1 start : var1, var2, var3 text 1 end

But I would like :

text 1 start : **var1, var2, var3**. text 1 end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return your data separately and use the normal LaTeX commands like `\Sexpr{foo} \textbf{\Sexpr{bar}} \textbf{\Sexpr{foobar}}`.

Alternatively, you could embed the necessary LaTeX command in R like this:

```
\documentclass[A4]{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
foo <- paste(1, 2, "\\\\textbf{", 3, "}", '4')
@

Test text with some \Sexpr{foo} with formatting.
\end{document}
```

Mind the multitude of backslashes necessary.

**Edit**:

For knitr the code needs some modificaitions:

```
\documentclass[A4]{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
foo <- paste(1, 2, "\\textbf{", 3, "}", '4')
@

Test text with some \Sexpr{asis_output(foo)} with formatting.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours answers.  For the second one, it displays textbf in the report and interprets \\ as a return to the line. Maybe because I'm using knitr ?

Comment: @JulietteC: Yes, knitr is almost but not fully compatible with Sweave – see my edit of the answer.