# \Sexpr cannot be parsed and evaluated if it includes LaTeX-commands

Tags: r, knitr

I am using RStudio and `knitr` to create a pdf. Using `\Sexpr()` I wanted to include inline code, which takes a vector and puts `\textbf{}` around it to make it bold, but it did not work. I found a solution here: [Put a part of a text in bold in \sexp with Sweave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170456/put-a-part-of-a-text-in-bold-in-sexp-with-sweave), but it requires to create an additional object beforehand and I would like to do everything inline, but then I receive an error:

> INCOMPLETE_STRING 1: asis_output(paste0("\\textbf{", test,"

It seems that adding LaTeX-commands into `\Sexpr()` cannot be parsed and evaluated, but I don't know why.

Here is a short example to show my problem:

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
test <- c("testA", "testB", "testC")
boldtest <- paste0("\\textbf{", test,"}", collapse = " and ")
@

\Sexpr{asis_output(boldtest)}\\
%\Sexpr{asis_output(paste0("\\textbf{", test,"}", collapse = " and "))}\\ % not working
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `\Sexpr` is parsed by `knitr` to end at the first occurence of `}`.  I don't think there's any way to avoid this, so you'll need a workaround like putting the closing brace into a variable.  For example,

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
test <- c("testA", "testB", "testC")
closebrace <- "}"
@

\Sexpr{asis_output(paste0("\\textbf{", test, closebrace, collapse = " and "))}\\ 
\end{document}
```

I find this kind of ugly, so I'd recommend defining a new R function to do the latex stuff, e.g.

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
test <- c("testA", "testB", "testC")
textbf <- function(text) 
  paste0("\\textbf{", text, "}")
@

\Sexpr{asis_output(paste0(textbf(test), collapse = " and "))}\\ 
\end{document}
```

If bolding isn't the only LaTeX you're inserting, you might want a more general function, with separate definitions for other operations:

```
LaTeXMacro <- function(text, macro) 
  paste0("\\", macro, "{", text, "}")

textbf <- function(text)
  LaTeXMacro(text, "textbf")

textit <- function(text)
  LaTeXMacro(text, "textit")
```